# weird behaviour of html5 canvas and jquery

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas

I'm starting to play with the html5 canvas. I'll be making pixel by pixel plots. To start, I wanted to make two rectangles pixel by pixel. The following code works:

```
<html>
<head>

<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.9.1" %>

<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>

<script type="text/javaScript">

function plotCanvas2d(mean,nx,nz,canvas)
{

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var imageData = context.createImageData(nx,nz);

var kk=0;
var blue;

for (var jj=0; jj<nz; ++jj) {
    for (var ii=0; ii<nx; ++ii) {

        blue = mean[ii][jj]*255;

        imageData.data[kk] = 0;
        imageData.data[kk+1] = 0;
        imageData.data[kk+2] = blue;
        imageData.data[kk+3] = 255;
        kk += 4;
    }
}

context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}

$(document).ready( function plotFull()
{

var nx = 600;
var nz = 300;

var mean = new Array(nx);

for (var ii=0; ii<nx; ii++)
{
    mean[ii] = new Array(nz);
}

for (var ii=0; ii<nx; ii++) {
    for (var jj=0; jj<nz; jj++)
    {
        mean[ii][jj] = 0.0;
    }
}


// $('#canvas').height(nz);
// $('#canvas').width(nx);
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

for (var jj=0; jj<nz/2; ++jj) {
    for (var ii=0; ii<nx; ++ii) { 
        mean[ii][jj] = 0; }}

for (var jj=nz/2; jj<nz; ++jj) {
    for (var ii=0; ii<nx; ++ii) {
        mean[ii][jj] = 1; }}

plotCanvas2d(mean,nx,nz,canvas)

});      

</script>

</head> 
<body>
<!-- <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas> -->
<canvas id="canvas" ></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

but If I uncomment the three commented lines, and comment the canvas definition on the html body, it doesn't. I was doing something much more complex and was able to nail the problem to this. If I set the size of the canvas in its definition, the code works. If I set the size using jquery, it doesn't. In the first case the image is a blue and black rectangle, in the second one only black. On the bigger piece of code, the behavior was pretty much unpredictable in the second case. What am I missing? it has to be something stupid, but I just can't see it...

Comment: You're mixing up your nz's and nx's, and iteration variables.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, try using

```
 $('#canvas').attr('width',600);
 $('#canvas').attr('height',300);
```

You need to set the width and height attribute I believe hence the .attr().

Also if using jquery I think you'd need to use:

```
var canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
```

to pass the canvas into your method rather then the jquery object.